# Finding number of ways of selecting 6 gloves each of different colour from 18 gloves?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are nine pairs of gloves each of different colors in how many ways can we select six gloves such that each is of different color?
I tried like this :
First number of ways in which we can select 6 colors out of nine it is $^9C_6$  ways. Then we can arrange it in 6! ways and also we can select either of two gloves out of the 6 in $2^6$ ways. Hence required number of ways should be $^9C_6$  .$2^6$.6!

Comment: What have you done and where are you having difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom{9}{6}$ ways of selecting the colours. For each chosen colour, we can choose the right glove or the left glove, for a total of $\binom{9}{6}2^6$.

Comment: Nice explanation